# AdventureWorks Sample DB

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, codeplex, sample-data, adventureworks

Could someone please help me with this. I would like to install the AWDB sample database to use with SharePoint 2010 on my Win7 dev system.

So SQL 2008 Express.
I have tried to download various things from codeplex, basically because I don't know the difference between the types. I have tried to look this up online in some blog posts but none of what I find/follow seem to work.

I think this is where I need to download what I need  [here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211), but I am not sure what I need exactly. At this point I am just trying to get the db in SQL right now, and I am maybe novice with sql at that point, but really just want to start experimenting with BCS in SP2010 anyway.

Any takers helping a rookie? Always appreciated! Thanks guys!

Comment: It isn't necessary to prefix your questions with the name of the technology you are using. The tag system is designed to let viewers know what programming language or software you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdventureWorks2008R2-Full Database Backup.zip would be fine.

Then in SQL Express use:

```
restore database [database_name] from disk = 'backup path'
  with move 'AdventureWorks2008R2_Data' to '<database_data_file_path>\<filename>.mdf',
       move 'AdventureWorks2008R2_Log' to '<database_log_file_path>\<filename>.ldf'
```

Comment: tried this and got the error 100.50.etc....researched and apparently found that I had an incompatible version of server to restore the bak. but ended up finding the correct link for 2008 so thanks!